# Помогите разобраться, что случилось

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Просто скопировал небольшой код с сайта (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/), перед этим создал бота в телеграмме (BotFather). Запускаю код и вижу такую ошибку в консоли

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен тоже взял у BotFather")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

bot.polling( none_stop = True )
```

Запускаю код и вижу такую ошибку в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо, буду благодарен!

Comment: Случился РосКомНадзор, блокирующий доступ к серверам Телеграм с территории РФ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Получается нужно использовать Vpn?

Comment: Да. Либо запускать код не на территории РФ.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо!

Comment: У меня есть ещё один вопрос, я написал код, подключился к VPN. Могут ли мои друзья/знакомые пользоваться данным ботом, находясь при этом в России?

Comment: Если могут пользоваться Телеграмом, то и ботами могут.